# Addition of uint32* with uint32

Tags: c

I am having trouble understanding pointer arithmetic. Any help will be appreciated.

```
uint32* valA = 0x80000000; 
uint32 valB = 0x7a0

valA += valB;
```

The value of valA is 0x80001e80. This is four times of valB.

Doubts I have:
1. why didnt the value of valA change to 0x800007a0. 
2. How can I get the valA to be incremented just with 0x7a0 and not four times the value of valB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic in C is scaled by the size of the type, which makes these two equivalent:

```
valA = valA + valB;
valA = &valA[valB];
```

If you want to force it to treat it as a byte offset, you'll need a cast to `char *` first:

```
valA = (uint32 *)((char *)valA + valB);
```

Comment: @delnan: Indeed. Any time you see casts, especially involving pointer types, one should always be suspicious ;).

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic is a matter of size of data the pointer is pointing to.

uint32 is 4 bytes large, that's because the result is four times valB.

The question is, why do you want you pointer incremented just by 0x7a0. That doesn't make sense in this situation. It's only useful if you need to access bytes. If you need just that, you would use pointers pointing to a byte.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an int to a pointer advances the pointer by that many instances of the datatype the pointer points to. That is, if your systems's `sizeof(uint)` is 4 bytes, the integer is multipled by 4 before being added to the pointer address.

Essentially, pointer math is isomorphic with array addressing. If `p` is a pointer and `i` is an integer, `p[i]` is the same as `*(p+i)` ... and in old C compilers, you could even write that as `i[p]` and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

A `uint32` takes 4 bytes of space. The next `uint32` after `&valA` occurs at `&((valA + 4U))`.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ pointer arithmetic must increase the value of the pointer by the size of the type object.

Say you have:

```
int a[2];
int* b = a;
```

At this point `b` points to the first element of `a`. Now, increment `b`.

```
++b;
```

You would expect `b` to point to the second element of `a`. The addresses of the first element of `a` and the second element of `a` are different by size of `int`. Hence, if the `++b` must increment the value of `b` by the size of `int`, not just one byte.